# SSIS .dtproj issue when converting from TFVC to GIT

Tags: git, ssis

Every time i open my SSIS solution it creates a database and updates the new database details in dtproj.

This is before i make any code changes. We moved from TFVC to GIT recently as well as upgraded from VS 2015 - VS 2017. In TFVC we never had this issue. Is there a setting we need to make on our side or an entry that needs to be added to gitignore to solve this issue?

The annoying part is i have to delete this database and undo the dtproj changes before i can move to another branch

[image]

Comment: That must not be a git problem (git don't touch your files or projects) but more a change of behavior in VS2017. Try to open your project in VS2015 to see if you still have this behavior. You can't git ignore the files. Look if it's a normal behavior and if needed, perhaps you have to commit it.

Comment: Hi Philippe, would you be able to send me a link to this VS documentation?

Comment: I don't have a documentation. I just told you that it is very unlikely that it is caused by git because that is not how git works and you should better try to look at the VS behavior when loading the project. And you can't git ignore a tracked file like the project file dtproj so that it not the solution either.